# Generating repetitive data in numpy / pandas in a fast vectorized way

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Suppose I want to generate a 1D array  like this:

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4
```

In general I am looking for something with this form:

```
Element     N-repetition
1           n-0
2           n-1
3           n-2
4           n-3
.           .
.           .
.           .
n           n-(n-1)=1
```

This is of course possible by combining arrays of
sizes n, n-1, n-2, ..., but I am wondering if there is
a better, vectorized way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its very simple with Numpy's `repeat`:

```
n = 4
a = np.arange(1,n+1)
```

The array `a` looks like:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

And you basically want to repeat it with the reverse of `a`, so:

```
np.repeat(a, a[::-1])
```

Gives:

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with something myself, but it's a little complicated:

```
def makegenarr(n):
    def genarr(x):
        return np.repeat(x, n-(x-1))
    return(genarr)

x = np.arange(1, 5)
mapfunc = makegenarr(x.shape[0])
np.apply_along_axis(genarr, 0, x)
```